# EXCEL VBA to select ROWS if Cell A5 contains specific text - caveats

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic

I receive an excel file daily. I am trying to select all ROWS if cells from A5 to the end of the dynamic data contains a string "TURNER 232"

- Cells A1 to A3 are blank
- Cells A4 are the column headings
- Cells A5 to the dynamic end of the sheet always contain "TURNER 232"

I have been copying various examples of code from this website to no avail.

Would appreciate any assistance if possible.

[image: Example]

Many thanks
Matt

Code used

```
Sub CustomSelect()
    Dim i As Long: i = 2
    Do While Range("H" & i).Value = "TURNER 232"
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    Range("A5:H" & i - 1).EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range.AutoFilter`?

Comment: You probably will not find code that exactly fits your need.  You will need to try and edit it for your needs.  Then you should bring the code that almost gets you there and explain the problem you are having.  Otherwise it sounds like you want us to write this code for you and that is not what this site is for.

Comment: Voting to close as `needs details`; with `vba` tagged, the code in question needs to be provided.

Comment: `Dim i As Long: i = 2` the `2` should be the first row that has `"TURNER 232"`  Which in your example is `5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott,

I used the below which did the trick.

Thanks mate.1st ever soiree into VBA

```
Sub CustomSelect()
     Dim i As Long: i = 5
     Do While Range("A" & i).Value = "TURNER 232"
        i = i + 1
     Loop
     Range("A5:A" & i - 1).EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```